# Duvida ActiveModel::Validations Ruby

Tags: ruby

good morning people

I'm trying to validate within the module if the email is valid but I'm getting an error can you help me?

> require 'active_model'
>
> class PixKey
>
> ```
> attr_accessor :key
> include ActiveModel::Validations
>
> def initialize(key)
> validate :key, format: { with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i }
> @key == :key
> end
> ```
>
> end
>
> person = PixKey.new('me@vishnuatrai.com') puts person.valid?

Err

> Uncaught exception: wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 0..1)
> /home/wesleybedeschi/.rbenv/versions/3.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/3.1.0/gems/activemodel-7.0.3/lib/active_model/validations.rb:334:in
> `valid?'

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `validates` method here not `validate`. Also you need to refactor your code a little bit like his:

```
Class Pixkey
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  
  attr_accessor :key

  validates :key, format: {with:/\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i }

  def initialize(key)
    @key = key
  end
end
```